# org.apache.commons.io.FileCleaningTracker does not delete temp files unless explicitly calling System.gc()?

Tags: jvm

I am working on a upload image feature for my web app, and am having a strange issue with the "FileCleaningTracker" from apache commons fileupload. I have a ImageUploadService with a instance variable FileCleaningTracker, then I have a upload method that creates an instance of  DiskFileItemFactory and then references the FileCleaningTracker, after the upload method completes successfully, I set the FileCleaningTracker of DiskFileItemFactory  to null, so i would expect the DiskFileItemFactory to be garbage collected and then the underlying subclass of PhantomReference in FileCleaningTracker will be notified hence delete the temp file the DiskFileItemFactory  created.

But that does not happen until I null the DiskFileItemFactory  and call System.gc() (only nulling the DiskFileItemFactory does not help) at the end of the upload method. THis seems very strange to me. Here is my code :

```
    @Override
    public void upload(final HttpServletRequest request) {

        ValidateUtils.checkNotNull(request, "upload request");

        final File tmp = new File(this.tempFolder);

        if (!tmp.exists()) {
            tmp.mkdir();
        }

        DiskFileItemFactory fileItemFactory = new DiskFileItemFactory(this.sizeThreshold, tmp);

        fileItemFactory.setFileCleaningTracker(this.fileCleaningTracker);

        ServletFileUpload uploadHandler = new ServletFileUpload(fileItemFactory);

        List items;
        try {
            items = uploadHandler.parseRequest(request);
        } catch (final FileUploadException e) {
            throw new ImageUploadServiceException("Error parsing the http servlet request for image upload.", e);
        }

        final Iterator it = items.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {

            final DiskFileItem item = (DiskFileItem) it.next();
            if (item.isFormField()) {

                // log message
            } else {

                final String fileName = item.getName();

                final File destination = this.createFileForUpload(fileName, this.uploadFolder);

                FileChannel outChannel;
                try {
                    outChannel = new FileOutputStream(destination).getChannel();
                } catch (final FileNotFoundException e) {
                    throw new ImageUploadServiceException(e);
                }
                FileChannel inChannel = null;
                try {

                    inChannel = new FileInputStream(item.getStoreLocation()).getChannel();
                    outChannel.transferFrom(inChannel, 0, item.getSize());
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    throw new ImageUploadServiceException(String.format("Error uploading image to '%s/%s'.", this.uploadFolder, destination.getName()), e);
                } finally {
                    IOUtils.closeChannel(inChannel);
                    IOUtils.closeChannel(outChannel);
                }

            }
        }
             fileItemFactory.setFileCleaningTracker(null);
}
```

The above code causes every upload creates a file in the temp folder but does not remove it at the end by the "fileCleaningTracker", possibly because the DiskFileItemFactory instance is not garbage collected(I've failed to see why it shouldn't have) or it has been GCed but not notified by the PhantomReference in fileCleaningTracker(how reliable is PhantomReference?)

I waited 10 minutes and the files are still there, so it should't be because the GC has not run. and there are no exceptions.

Now if I add the following code, the temp files are removed every time after the upload:

```
    fileItemFactory = null;
    System.gc();
```

This looks very strange to me as I would expect the fileItemFactory be GCed without an explict call to System.gc().

Any input will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

I have the same problem. The temporary files are never removed even after the server shutdown: GC process had not been started so `FileCleaningTracker` had no chance to get tracked files to delete from `ReferenceQueue` and all the files remain on the hard drive.

Due to specific behavior of my application I have to clean up after each upload (files might be very big). Instead of using standard `org.apache.commons.io.FileCleaningTracker` I am feeling lucky to override this class with my own implementation:

```
/**
 * Cleaning tracker to clean files after each upload with special method invocation.
 * Not thread safe and must be used with 1 factory = 1 thread policy.
 */
public class DeleteFilesOnEndUploadCleaningTracker extends FileCleaningTracker {

     private List<String> filesToDelete = new ArrayList();

     public void deleteTemporaryFiles() {
         for (String file : filesToDelete) {
             new File(file).delete();
         }
         filesToDelete.clear();
     }

     @Override
     public synchronized void exitWhenFinished() {
         deleteTemporaryFiles();
     }

     @Override
     public int getTrackCount() {
         return filesToDelete.size();
     }

     @Override
     public void track(File file, Object marker) {
         filesToDelete.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
     }

     @Override
     public void track(File file, Object marker, FileDeleteStrategy deleteStrategy) {
         filesToDelete.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
     }

     @Override
     public void track(String path, Object marker) {
         filesToDelete.add(path);
     }

     @Override
     public void track(String path, Object marker, FileDeleteStrategy deleteStrategy) {
         filesToDelete.add(path);
     }
 }
```

If this the right case for you just inject the instance of the class above into your `DiskFileItemFactory`:

```
DeleteFilesOnEndUploadCleaningTracker tracker = new DeleteFilesOnEndUploadCleaningTracker();
fileItemFactory.setFileCleaningTracker(tracker);
```

And don't forget to invoke the cleaning method after your work with uploaded items is done:

```
tracker.deleteTemporaryFiles();
```

Forgot to mention: I use `commons-fileupload` version 1.2.2 and `commons-io` version 1.3.2.